# How to i18n dropdown menu populated from database table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, model, internationalization, simple-form

I have form with dropdown menu, which is populated from model:

```
<%= f.association :cargo_price, :label_method => :price, :value_method => :id %>
```

There is model called **cargo_price** with only **ID** and **price** columns. I would like to i18n this selection. Is there any best practice for such a case?

I had an idea to rename **price** column to **price_en**, and add another language mutation as separate columns. But I do not know, how to instruct **simple_form** to load correct column as label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to figure solution by myself, based on already solved similar problems, described on Internet forums and QA. Prerequisite is, there is model CargoPrice, with 3 records:

```
ID | Price
---------------
 1 | all_in
 2 | plus_plus
 3 | make_offer
```

So first of all I created new method in **CargoPrice** model, this method is named **translated_price**:

```
def translated_price
  I18n.t(price, :scope => 'cargo_price')
end
```

Next step was to define correct translation to **en.yaml** / other language file:

```
en:
  cargo_price:
    all_in: "All in"
    plus_plus: "++"
    make_offer: "Make an offer"
```

And last step was to change form to (note **label_method**):

```
<%= f.association :cargo_price, label_method => :translated_price, :value_method => :id %>
```

Now, dropdown selection box is populated from model, and every select-able option is translated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Rails Internationalization guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). The convention is to use Rails translation helpers:

```
I18n.t 'store.title'
```

These reference values in a translation yaml file:

```
en:
  store:
    title: "Example Store"
de:
  store:
    title: "Beispiel Speicher"
```

In your case, it sounds like you want to apply translations to your model column names. I would not advise doing that, your `cargo_price` model should be the same regardless of the language it is being translated into.

Comment: Thanx for an answer, I think I did not explained it well. Let me give you example. Model **cargo_price** has column called **price** there are 3 values (rows) in that model. for example: Small, Middle, Large. Form is feed from this model, so there is dropdown box filled wit these values. Now based on translation, i need to translate these values from model to another language. So I donot think I can use standard <language>.yml file?

Comment: If these three `cargo_prices` do not change often then you could still use <language>.yml. For example, you could do `I18n.t "store.#{price.first}"`. If you did want separate columns, `price`, `price_en`, then this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478625/translate-database-fields-with-rails) may help you. However, as you can see from the answers on that thread, it is probably not a good solution.